# Migrating mySql datatables to Clodant Documents

Tags: couchdb, cloudant, nosql

We are planning to move from MySql to Cloudant NoSql. I want to understand what would be the best approach to do that.
We have 5 different tables--Product (ProductId Primary key), Issues (IssueId primary key, ProductId Foreign key) and Tags (Tag id Primary key, ProductId Foreign key) and Location (LocationId primary key location as foreign key with location in product table) and Policy (policyId primary key, IssueId as primary key).

Now we are thought of two approaches for maintaining documents in Cloudant.

1. Keep different documents for each row with unique document type per table (for each table one document type ex document types as "product","issues,"tag","location","policy" ).
2. Keep different document for each row with all relation defined in one document (all documents with type "product" only where maintaining all tags,issues[policies],location per product).

Which approach is better?

Answer (score 0):

The answer really depends on the size and rate of growth of your data. In previous SQL->NoSQL migrations, I've used your second approach (I don't know your exact schema, so I'll guess):

```
{ 
   _id: "prod1",
   name: "My product",
   tags: [
     "red", "sport", "new"
   ],
   locations: [
     {
       location_id: "55",
       name: "London",
       latitude: 51.3,
       longitude: 0.1
     }
   ],
   issues: [
     {
       issue_id: "466",
       policy_id: "88",
       name: "issue name"
     }
   ]
}
```

This approach allows you to get almost everything about a product in a single Cloudant API call (`GET /products/prod1`). Such a call will give you all of your primary product data and what would have been joins in a SQL world - in this case arrays of things or arrays of objects.

You may still want another database of `locations` or `policies` because you may want to store extra information about those objects in separate collections, but you can store a *sub-set* of that data (e.g. the location's name and geo position) in the product document. This does mean duplicating some data from your reference "locations" collection inside each product, but leads to greater efficiency at query time (at the expense of making updates to the data more complicated).

It all depends about how you access the data. For speed and efficiency you want to be able retrieve the data you need to render a page in as few API calls as possible. If you keep everything in its own database, then you need to *do the joins yourself*, because Cloudant doesn't have joins. This would be inefficient because you would need an extra API call for each "join".

There is [another way to managed "joins" in Cloudant](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43825864/how-to-do-a-nosql-linked-query/43828473#43828473) and this may be suitable if your secondary collections are large e.g. if the number of locations/tags/issues would make the product document size too large.